# @RegisterProvider not working for provider in an quarkus extension

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-rest-client, quarkus-reactive

I have a quarkus rest reactive implementation which uses a quarkus extension which I created. The extension is meant to intercept both the front side (server) and back side (client) requests and responses. The front side filter behaves as it should, however the back end client interceptors are not called when used from the extension file. If the client filter is copied directly in the service code it works, but, doesn't work when referenced from the extension.

**The deployment for the extension has this:**

```java
class QuarkusMvpMessageHandlerExtProcessor {

    private static final String FEATURE = "quarkus-message-handler-v1-ext";

    @BuildStep
    FeatureBuildItem feature() {
        return new FeatureBuildItem(FEATURE);
    }

    @BuildStep
    AdditionalBeanBuildItem additionalBeans() {
        return new AdditionalBeanBuildItem(MessageHandlerFrontSideRequestHandler.class, 
            MessageHandlerFrontSideResponseHandler.class,MessageUtilValidationRules.class, 
            MessageUtilConfigurationImpl.class, MessageUtilConfigurationsImpl.class,     MessageHandlerClientRequestFilter.class,MessageHandlerClientResponseFilter.class,RequestScopedContext.class,MessageUtilSoapValidator.class, SOAP11ClientMessageHandler.class, 
                SOAP12ClientMessageHandler.class);
   }
// ....
}
```

**as well as** the empty beans.xml file in the runtime META-INF directory

**The backend filter (Clientin the extension file:**

```java
@Provider
@ApplicationScoped
public class MessageHandlerClientRequestFilter {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageHandlerClientRequestFilter.class);

    @Inject
    RequestScopedContext requestScopedContext;

    @Inject
    MessageUtilValidationRules messageUtilValidationRules;

    @Inject
    MessageUtilConfigurations messageUtilConfigurations;

    public void handleRequest(ClientRequestContext clientRequestContext) {
        LOGGER.debug("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ MessageHandlerClientRequestFilter  handlePropgation");
    }
// ...
}
```

**And this in the service which includes the client filter from extension:**

```java
/**
 * @RegisterRestClient Register the Interface as a Rest Client with setup Api endpoint
 * configured
 * @RegisterClientHeaders request headers by registering a ClientHeadersFactory
 * @RegisterProvider MessageHandlerClientRequestFilter and MessageHandlerClientResponseFilter 
 * are registered as providers to act as back end interceptors
 */
@RegisterProvider(MessageHandlerClientRequestFilter.class)
@RegisterProvider(MessageHandlerClientResponseFilter.class)
@RegisterRestClient(configKey="rest-service-one")
@RegisterClientHeaders(Service1HeaderFactory.class)
public interface RestService1 {

    @GET
    @Path("/rest1/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Uni<Response> getByIdAsync(@PathParam("id") String id);

}
```

I tried using it by including the classes from the jar for the extension:

```xml
<quarkus-message-handler-version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</quarkus-message-handler-version>
```

I was expecting both the front side (server) filters and the back side client filters to work.

Only the front side filters are working the back side are never called.

Comment: So you are saying that `MessageHandlerClientResponseFilter` and `MessageHandlerClientRequestFilter` are not being called?

What do those look like?

Comment: Resolved - added implements ClientRequestFilter and ClientResponseFilter which for some reason isn't needed when the filter is in the same repo as the service.
Going to experiment with @provider stuff to find out why

Answer (score 0):

Resolved - added implements ClientRequestFilter and ClientResponseFilter which for some reason isn't needed when the filter is in the same repo as the service and both @provider on the filter and client has @RegisterProvider. Going to experiment with @Provider and @RegisterProvider stuff to find out why

Answer (score 0):

Resolved - added implements ClientRequestFilter and ClientResponseFilter which for some reason isn't needed when the filter is in the same repo as the service and both @provider on the filter and client has @RegisterProvider. Going to experiment with @Provider and @RegisterProvider stuff to find out why

Also added
@ActivateRequestContext - to get request scoped to be available from front side to back

```
@Provider
@ApplicationScoped
@ActivateRequestContext
public class MessageHandlerClientRequestFilter implements ClientRequestFilter {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageHandlerClientRequestFilter.class);

    @Inject
    RequestScopedContext requestScopedContext;
```